# Do we say "I made a boo boo" instead of "I made a mistake" when we want to joke?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

I have just watched the film "Champions 2023".

In the film, the man swore or used some bad words and the other man said "**No boo-boo words**".

I checked the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boo-boo) and

> **boo-boo**: a mistake:
>
> Oops, I think I made a boo-boo there - I hope she's not too upset.

I am not sure if "**No boo-boo words**" means "**No mistake words**"?

Also, "**boo-boo**" sounds funny

Do we say "**I made a boo boo**" instead of "**I made a mistake**" when we want to joke?

Comment: _Boo-boo_ is an informal, rather childish word for a mistake (Collins says it's American). Using it to describe swear-words sounds an unusual usage to me.

Comment: Using childish words in conversation with adults is fraught with danger! Even native speakers can make themselves look stupid by doing this in contexts where it's "not quite appropriate", and non-native speakers have little chance of being able to accurately assess whether the current context (and likely attitudes of other conversants) will allow such use (facetiously or otherwise).

Comment: *I am not sure if "No boo-boo words" means "No mistake words".* Not in this context, where the speaker seems to want it to mean 'rude' or  'naughty'.

Comment: I think that the script writers are bending the meaning a bit here. By boo-boo they mean it was a mistake to use the word rather than the word itself was a mistake.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'Using childish words in conversation with adults' - I think the adults in question have intellectual disabilities.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I haven't seen the movie yet. But in general I disapprove of using childish language with "adults", even if they're "intellectually challenged". I think that kind of thing encourages carers to "talk down" to their charges in the real world. And it's all downhill once respect is lost, even if it puts bums on seats in movieland.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -I couldn't agree more. Well said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adults, especially adult learners, should normally avoid such infantile expressions.  Native speakers might be able to "get away with it" as a joke, but it would just come over as odd for an adult.

Adult learners should normally use "mother" and not "mummy", for example

"Boo boo" is used when talking for children as a replacement for a more adult term that might be thought to be too serious or strict.  You might say "You've got a boo boo on your knee" to mean "a minor injury, cut or graze". Make a boo boo might mean make a mistake, without the implication of failure that "mistake" has.  And from context "boo boo words" are swear words. There are probably other examples of childish use of "boo boo" to mean "something unpleasant which I don't want to speak about directly".

Comment: 'Boo boo" is used when talking to children...' - maybe worth noting - summary of film: _A former minor-league basketball coach receives a court order to manage a team of players with intellectual disabilities._